# I- Net Crystal Clear Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I need consultation.
I have next  problem.
In report page i have 
-header 
-details
-footer

In every page i have different counts of records. In header i want show id of first record and id of last record in page. How i can make this? Because last record in page i can get only in last iteration in details or in footer of page. But main problem that i need to know last record in page in header of page. The way to put some number for every page - i can not make this, because differents records have different size of information(some records have 3 lines, some 4 lines) and it can be free space in page

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: i need get this only in report template file. work with report from JAVA.